# Setting final variables in superclass from subclass

Tags: inheritance, final

I have the following abstract class Piece that uses an Asset (Asset is nothing more that just x, y, width, height and some other special variables I set up) as a superclass.

```
public abstract class Piece extends Asset {

    private final int blockWidth;
    private final int blockHeight;

    public Piece(int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage image) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.image = image;
        pieceInit();
    }
```

I have a couple of other classes that extend Piece. They all pretty much look this this:

```
public class IBlock extends Piece {

    private final int blockWidth
    private final int blockHeight;

    public IBlock(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height, IMAGE);
        this.blockWidth = width / 4;
        this.blockHeight = height;
    }
```

I want to calculate the blockWidth and blockHeight of a Piece in its subclass, IBlock, without changing any constructors. I also want to delete blockWidth and blockHeight from IBlock. Is there any way I can force a subclass, IBlock, to set final variables in its constructor (using super) for its superclass, Piece?

Hopefully that makes some sense.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign final variables of the base class within a derived class' constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734377/how-can-i-assign-final-variables-of-the-base-class-within-a-derived-class-const)

Comment: _"Is there any way I can force a subclass, IBlock, to set final variables in its constructor (using super) for its superclass"_ -- no. But you can use a `static` method to compute the appropriate values, then pass them to the base class constructor. See proposed duplicate for examples.

Comment: Your question is too vague to know whether you are able to modify the base class, but assuming you can, or assuming there is already a constructor that allows the derived class to pass the block values to the base class, that's the way to do it. If not, you may have to "fake it", by modifying the width and height passed to the base class, so that it calculates the block dimensions according to what you want.